# How to query when all the boolean value all nested elements is false

Tags: solr

I want to query all parent docs where isDiscoverable is false in all nested elements.

Sample doc:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "6b8db630ad114492b95e47181565c1do",
    "assetType": "assetType",
    "assetKind": "assetKind",
    "designName": "designName",
    "designConceptId": "designConceptId",
    "designUseCaseId": "designUseCaseId",
    "designUseCaseName": "designUseCaseName",
    "productId": "productId",
    "productName": "productName",
    "designPhysicalSpecId": "designPhysicalSpecId",
    "mcpSku": "abcd",
    "tags": [
      "Tag 3",
      "Tag 4"
    ],
    "content_type": "parentDocument",
    "assetVersions": [
      {
        "id": "6b8db630ad114492b95e47181565c1dq",
        "isDiscoverable": false
      },
      {
        "id": "6b8db630ad114492b95e47181565c1db",
        "isDiscoverable": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Kindly help me to write the query.